# How to setup SSL for Socket.IO installed together with virtual host in WHM CentOS7?

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, centos7

My current project is serving the website using CPanel in a CentOS 7 WHM dedicated machine. I use node.js socket.io to send realtime update to the site and the nodejs files are also in the same directory as the site files. To connect my socket.io-client, this is what I placed in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.com\:8080$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitename\.com\:8080$
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:8080\/$1" [P,L]
```

In my server.js, I simply listen to port 8080

```
server.listen(8080);
```

And in my socket.io-client side

```
var socket = io.connect('http://sitename.com:8080',
    {'force new connection':true,
    'transports':['websocket']});
```

Everything works but I recently applied SSL to the site and in an attempt to use SSL connection in my socket.io-client, I tried changing the .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^sitename\.com\:8080$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.sitename\.com\:8080$
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:8080\/$1" [P,L]
```

and the socket.io-client to

```
var socket = io.connect('https://sitename.com:8080',
    {'force new connection':true,
    'transports':['websocket']});
```

But I wasn't able to connect to my nodejs server. Is my current setup wrong? Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the above .htaccess code was not needed at all. Just adding the port used by the socket.io in the WHM firewall was enough to make the connection, no reverse proxy needed. To make https work with my socket.io, all it took was modifying the server.js to use https and using the proper keys and certificate file already installed:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var prvKey = fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/keys/123.key').toString();
var prvCert = fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/cert/123.crt').toString();
var server = https.createServer({key:prvKey,cert:prvCert});
server.listen(8080);
```